# ASP .net Always ask for log in on load

Tags: c#, asp.net

I'm using ASP.net with C#, I have a form with master page and I need to show the log in everytime someone enters the page and logout when the information in the form is saved in database.

To save I use this code

```
<asp:Button ID="botonAcepto"
                            Text="Guardar"
                            runat="server"
                            ValidationGroup="validaARCO"
                            OnClick="btnUpload_Click" />
```

btnUpload_Click uses this code to redirect to logout

```
string scriptText = "alert('Datos guardados exitosamente.'); location.href='/folder/folder/logout.aspx';";
ScriptManager.RegisterStartupScript(this, this.GetType(), "alertMessage", scriptText, true);
```

But, when I try to force the log in page the button doesn't work. 
I tried this 3 ways to force login on load. These page loads are not in the same document at the same time, they're the 3 set ups I tried on my Default.aspx.cs to force the login at load.

```
protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        if (!IsPostBack)
        {
            HttpCookie cookie1 = new HttpCookie(FormsAuthentication.FormsCookieName, "");
            cookie1.Expires = DateTime.Now.AddYears(-1);
            Response.Cookies.Add(cookie1);
        }
    }

protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    if (!IsPostBack)
    {
        FormsAuthentication.SignOut();
        Response.Cookies[FormsAuthentication.FormsCookieName].Expires = DateTime.Now.AddYears(-1);
        HttpContext.Current.User = new GenericPrincipal(new GenericIdentity(string.Empty), null);
        MaxUsersManager.RemoveSessionCacheItem(Context);
        Session.Clear();
        Session.Abandon();
    }
}

protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    if (!IsPostBack)
    {
        FormsAuthentication.SignOut();
        FormsAuthentication.RedirectToLoginPage();
    }
}
```

The 3 examples make the button useless, and the form goes to the login page and doesn't save the data.

How can I solve this? Is there any other way to always force the user to log in to enter the form and log out when the data is saved?
Thanks.

Comment: Those Page_Loads are from the logout.aspx page?

Comment: @kblok No, the Page_Loads are from my main page.

Comment: Why don't you code the logout in the button click?

Comment: @kblok It's there, but if the user is previously logged in from other part of the site, it doesn't ask for the log in.